# Transparency vs. White background in Inkscape

Tags: transparency, inkscape

I am using Inkscape and I know how to use transparency within the image, but I am annoyed that the background of the workspace in Inkscape is white. I searched through a lot of settings, but had no luck.

**How do I get the workspace checkered like in GIMP?**

The white workspace is really bothersome if you design something in white

Comment: Question is closed so I can't add a real answer anymore. Go to File > Document Properties. At the top of the Page tab you see Background with a color next to it. Click the color. Now select the RGB tab. In the hex value input type something like 888888FF. The 888888 is the color, the FF is the alpha, meaning fully transparent. Your document should now have a gray background.

Comment: @Luke As far as I know, alpha of 00 is is fully transparent.  The problem is that even if you change it to 00, in the document view it's shown as white.

Comment: If you're exporting a bitmap from the SVG, you can draw a box behind the image while working, then use the "Hide all except selected" option when exporting. If you place it on a locked layer, then selecting everything else is pretty easy.

Answer (score 10):

You can change the background color in Inkscape by changing the document properties (in the File menu).

In particular, you can check 'Checkerboard background' to show the checkerboard if the background is set to transparent.

Comment: I already tried that, but that doesn't do what I want it to. I just want the workspace checkered like in GIMP or Photoshop so I can see what I am designing :D

Answer (score 7):

A quite ugly solution is to design your own checker background and have it as locked bottom layer :) Im doing something similar when im fiddling around with iOS icons or items that will be on a background.

Also as Juve mention you could try out the grids property.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, a hint on transparency. If you export images with transparency  for example to PDF (for printing), they are converted to bitmaps inside the PDF or produce unwanted results. Export to non-vector formats should be fine. I suggest to avoid transparency, usually there is a way to mimic transparency, e.g., by just using a light gray for shadows. Also don't use blur effects; similar problems with PDF export.

Now to the checkboard:
It's not possible, one workaround would be to add full page sized box and choose black checker board as fill. Put this box on a separate layer and lock the layer. You might also lighten that box up using one of the filters. Unfortunately this board won't adapt when zooming.

Maybe not the solution, but a related option would be the grid (press #). This is not behind your drawing but in front. It can help you with positioning. Maybe you were looking for this?